# Scala, Currying on multi parameter-group method?

Tags: scala, currying

I am wondering if it is possible to use currying on multi parameter-group functions :

```
scala> def sum(a: Int)(b: Int): Int = { a+b }
sum: (a: Int)(b: Int)Int

scala> sum(3)(4)
res2: Int = 7

scala> val partFunc = sum(3) _
partFunc: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> partFunc(4)
res3: Int = 7

scala> val partFunc2 = sum _ _
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '_' found.
       val partFunc2 = sum _ _
                             ^

scala> val partFunc2 = (sum _) _
<console>:8: error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Int => (Int => Int)
       val partFunc2 = (sum _) _
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing simply `sum _` does not yet have anything to do with the arguments of `sum`, but simply distinguishes the *function object* `sum` from an *application* of the function.

Hence, you can write:

```
scala> val partFunc2 = sum _
partFunc2: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>
```

As you can see from the type information, this is already the curried version of `sum` which takes two `Int` parameters.

Of course, you can then proceed as before with `partFunc2(4)` being of type `Int => Int` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
val partFunc2 = sum _
```

or like this:

```
val partFunc2 = sum(3) _
```