# Scala, Currying on multi parameter-group method including implicit params?

Tags: scala, currying

After having discovered that [currying multi parameter-groups method is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10880982/595223), I am trying to get a partially applied function which requires implicit parameters.

It seams not possible to do so. If not could you explain me why ?

```
scala> def sum(a: Int)(implicit b: Int): Int = { a+b }
sum: (a: Int)(implicit b: Int)Int

scala> sum(3)(4)
res12: Int = 7

scala> val partFunc2 = sum _
<console>:8: error: could not find implicit value for parameter b: Int
       val partFunc2 = sum _
                       ^
```

I use a singleton object to create this partially applied function and I want to use it in a scope where the implicit int is defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because you don't have an implicit Int in scope. See:

```
scala> def foo(x: Int)(implicit y: Int) = x + y
foo: (x: Int)(implicit y: Int)Int

scala> foo _
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for parameter y: Int
              foo _
              ^

scala> implicit val b = 2
b: Int = 2

scala> foo _
res1: Int => Int = <function1>
```

The implicit gets replaced with a real value by the compiler. If you curry the method the result is a function and functions can't have implicit parameters, so the compiler has to insert the value at the time you curry the method.

edit:

For your use case, why don't you try something like:

```
object Foo {
  def partialSum(implicit x: Int) = sum(3)(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But as I said, I need to declare this function in another singleton object. I need to declare it out of the context where I use it.

Comment: edited my post. I think there is no other way of doing this, for the reasons I already mentioned.

Comment: You are right. As currying gives Function and Function does not allow implicit params, I need to explictly list the params of one of the two groups.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> object MySingleton {
 |   def sum(a: Int)(implicit b: Int): Int = { a+b }
 |  
 |
 |   def caller(a: Int) =  {
 |     implicit val b = 3; // This allows you to define the partial below
 |     def pf = sum _      // and call sum()() without repeating the arg list. 
 |     pf.apply(a)
 |   }
 | } 
defined module MySingleton


scala> MySingleton.caller(10)
res10: Int = 13
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, consider leaving some intuitive explanation, instead of just posting the code.